# How to play a Video with mpv with multiple audio streams

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mp4

I try to play a movie in two languages.
Audio 1 to Speaker
Audio 2 to Headset

```
mpv --lavfi-complex="[aid1] [aid2] amix [ao]" "input.mp4"
```

Play the video and mix audio1 & audio2 and output is standard device

```
mpv "input.mp4" --vid=1 --aid=1 --audio-device="wasapi/{d3178b30-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}"
```

Play video with audio1

```
mpv "input.mp4" --aid=2 --no-video --audio-device="wasapi/{06a44940-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}"
```

Play audio2 only

how to combine this?

Comment: Not sure what you wan to do. You have MP4 file with multiple audios? You want to send audio 1 to a specific playback device and audio 2 to a different playback device?

Comment: Yes, 1 MP4 (or MKV) with multiple audios (languages).

At the moment I try this:

mpv test.mkv --aid=1 --audio-device="wasapi/{headphone}" | mpv test.mkv --aid=2 --no-video --audio-device="wasapi/{speaker}"

but this open 2 instances of player and I can't "pause" at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This ugly script I wrote will play audio track 1 and 2 at the same time if the video is located in a specific folder. I use this to check my Shadowplay recordings as they have an option for split audio tracks.

Put it in a file called `anything.lua` in `%appdata%\mpv\scripts` or whatever the linux equivalent is (only tested on Windows though) and edit the `folderPath` as necessary.

```lua
local folderPath = "F:\\Shadowplay"

local function starts_with(str, start)
    return str:sub(1, #start) == start
 end

mp.register_event("file-loaded", function(event)
    if (starts_with(mp.get_property("working-directory"), folderPath) and mp.get_property_number("track-list/count") > 2) then
        mp.set_property('options/lavfi-complex', "[aid1] [aid2] amix [ao]")
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully done this by creating a 5.1 stream with one language mixed down to [FL] and [FR] and another to [BL] and [BR].
That I sent either directly to a multi-channel hardware (via ALSA) or through JACK to be more flexible with the channel routing.

This *might* be possible using mpv’s --lavfi-complex but I always prepared the 5.1 stream using ffmpeg.

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation